# Can't make CollectionViewCells appear even though are registered

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've read through all other people's questions and answers but still can't figure out what is wrong with my code and why on earth the cells are not displaying -

I am using `Storyboard` in my project, but chose to create the `UICollectionView` programmatically. The custom cells for the collectionView are `xib` files.

So I have a HomeViewController in which I have:

```
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView = UICollectionView(
    frame: .zero,
    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, _ -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        return HomeViewController.createSectionLayout(section: sectionIndex)
    }
)
```

and inside `viewDidLoad` I register the 3 custom `xib` cells I want to use in my collectionView:

```
collectionView.register(FeaturedPlaylistCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Constants.Cells.FEATURED_PLAYLIST)
    collectionView.register(NewReleasesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Constants.Cells.NEW_RELEASES)
    collectionView.register(RecommendedTrackCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Constants.Cells.RECOMMENDATION)
    
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
```

Each of the cells has a `xib` file with an `identifier` and a matching custom class with the same name as the xib file.

Inside the `cellForItemAt` I decide which cell I want to display by:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let type = sections[indexPath.section] // I identify properly which cell I want
    switch type {
        
    case .newReleases(let viewModels):
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Constants.Cells.NEW_RELEASES, for: indexPath) as? NewReleasesCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        return cell
    case .featuredPlaylists(let viewModels):
        // same code, different identifier and different as? collectionViewCell

    case .recommendedTracks(let viewModels):
         // same code, different identifier and different as? collectionViewCell
    }
}
```

Even though I added some labels and an image to my `NewReleasesCollectionViewCell`, for some reason the cells are not displaying and I just can't figure out why -.-

Any help would be appreciated

Edit:
For example my `NewReleasesCollectionViewCell` has the `identifier` "newReleases_Cell" saved into the `Constants` file and has the `custom class` called "NewReleasesCollectionViewCell". I do not have any code added yet to this file, just added some `labels` with text and in `imageview` in the xib itself

Comment: `frame: .zero`: If the collectionView isn't "visible", if it doesn't have some frame, meaning that it needs to display some cell inside a rect, it won't call cellFor Row at... So: Is the collectionView "visible" on screen? If not `collectionView(_; cellForItemAt:)` won't be called. is that method called?

Comment: "Each of the cells has a xib file with an identifier" But your code does not indicate that fact. There is nothing in your code that tell the runtime to use those xib files. So I would expect your cells to be empty. Are they?

Comment: "Even though I added some labels and an image to my NewReleasesCollectionViewCell" No. You added the labels to a xib file that isn't being used.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that these lines:

```
collectionView.register(FeaturedPlaylistCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Constants.Cells.FEATURED_PLAYLIST)
```

... all tell the runtime to *make* a *new* cell instance based on the name of the class. But what you want is for the runtime to *fetch* the *existing* cell instance from a xib file.

For that, you would use a different method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618083-register

Notice that the first parameter here is a UINib object, not a class.